# Android studio sting to Date time format

Tags: android, datetime-format

I'm new in android dev. I have this string

```
String gpsT="102030" // time format HHmmss 
String gpsD="240214" // date format ddMMyy
```

How do i convert this into DateTime format `"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"`?

Expected output: `Feb 24, 2014 10:20:30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below method:

```
public static String convertDate(String date, String dateFormate) {
    // here date = gpsD+" "+gpsT;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

    Date destDate;
    try {
        destDate = format.parse(date);
        return destFormat.format(destDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```